# Why would the LM Prediction function in R add a row to my output

Tags: r, prediction, kaggle

I am trying to use the predict function in R based of a basic linear model. My test set has 1459 values, but when I use the predict function it is creating 1460. I tried removing the NAs from the test set and even tried keeping them in, but do not know where this value is coming from.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

```
MODEL <- lm(train$SalePrice ~ train$LotArea * train$GarageArea * 
factor(train$FullBath) * train$YearBuilt * factor(train$OverallQual))



test_final <-read.csv("/Users/ERIC/Documents/HOUSING_PRICES/test.csv", 
        header = TRUE)


    na.omit(test_final)


    prediction <- data.frame(predict(MODEL, test_final))


    Warning messages:
    1: 'newdata' had 1459 rows but variables found have 1460 rows 
    2: In predict.lm(MODEL, test_final) :
    prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading
```

Data via: https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data

Comment: Hard to know but you should first try to use R formulas the way they were designed to operate. Do _NOT_ use "$" inside formulas. Try `MODEL <- lm( SalePrice ~ LotArea * GarageArea * 
factor(FullBath) * YearBuilt * factor(OverallQual), data=train)` . Voting to close for no data.

Comment: I appreciate it. I tried that for no luck. Will add data.

Comment: You have to reassign `test_final`, as in `test_final <- na.omit(test_final)`.

Comment: @Eric, using formulas appropriately will solve your issue. You will get a different error message, but this one will be more meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a note: you have to reassign the output of `na.omit()` to get rid of missing values.

See here:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(0, 10, NA))
df
  x  y
1 1  0
2 2 10
3 3 NA
na.omit(df)
  x  y
1 1  0
2 2 10
df
  x  y
1 1  0
2 2 10
3 3 NA
```

As you can see, the last call to `df` showed you the initial version including the `NA`s. You will need to reassign using `df <- na.omit(df)`.

---

The actual issue:

As pointed out by @42 in the comments, using formulas correctly will resolve this issue, i.e. you will not have this error message any longer. You will however have a different one. First, let me show you:

```
#read in the data
testdf <- read.csv("test.csv")
train <- read.csv("train.csv")

# run initial model, and run model as suggested by 42
model_original <- lm(train$SalePrice ~ train$LotArea * train$GarageArea * factor(train$FullBath) * train$YearBuilt * factor(train$OverallQual))

mod_42 <- lm(SalePrice ~ LotArea * GarageArea * factor(FullBath) * YearBuilt * factor(OverallQual), data = train)
```

Now, let us run predictions:

```
prediction <- data.frame(predict(model_original, testdf))
Warning messages:
1: 'newdata' had 1459 rows but variables found have 1460 rows 
2: In predict.lm(model_original, testdf) :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading
```

This led to the same error as you have. Now, let us run the predictions using the second approach:

```
prediction <- data.frame(predict(mod_42, testdf))
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor factor(FullBath) has new levels 4
```

Note that the error message is different now, and points to a more interesting problem.

Comment: I appreciate it. That is definitely cleaner and am now getting
 Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor factor(FullBath) has new levels 4
which has to do with how I am passing the variable via predict. Thanks @coffeinjunky